# Using the lambda Include method in a compiled LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, self-tracking-entities

I'm currently trying to optimize some of the LINQ queries in my program by precompiling them.
Some of these queries make extensive use of eager loading; here's an example of one:

```
public static Func<DatabaseEntities, string, IQueryable<Employee>> GetAllByName =
              CompiledQuery.Compile<DatabaseEntities, string, IQueryable<Employee>
              ((context, name) => context.Employees
                     .Include(e => e.Email)
                     .Where(e => e.LastName == name));
```

Example use:

```
var employees = GetAllByName(dbContext, "Bob").ToList();
```

Unfortunately, attempting to use this results in the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable[Employee]  Include[Employee,Email] (System.Linq.IQueryable[Employee], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[System.Func[Employee,Email]]) ' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I've noticed that the normal method of eager loading (Include(string)) works fine within a precompiled query.  Is there a way to use the lambda version as well?

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

You cannot use the lambda within a precompiled linq statement/query.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit code precompile such as:

```
public static Func<DatabaseEntities, string, IQueryable<Employee>> GetAllByName =
              CompiledQuery.Compile<DatabaseEntities, string, IQueryable<Employee>
              ((context, name) => context.Employees
                     .Include("Email")
                     .Where(e => e.LastName == name));
```